# Jquery Multiple Call POST Ajax single call back not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make mutiple Jquery post request parallelly but i need a single callback once all Jquery post request are done so that i can run another function which do the same thing.

below is my function

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );

    var mylist = createList(data_list);
    console.log("control flow is here");
      //make another 10 post call and wait for them to finish

    var mylist = createList(new_data_list);


        function createList(data_list){
            var ajaxlist=[];

            for(data of data_list){
            var senddata={teamdata:JSON.stringify(data)};
             var ajax_obj =$.post( "/fetchdata",senddata,function(result){
             $('#restult').html(result)
             });
             ajaxlist.push(ajax_obj);
            }

            $.when(ajaxlist.join(',')).then(function() {
                $('.mytitle').html('ssssss');

                // All requests are done
            });
        }
});
```

I have Jquery when to make request but it seem that Jquery When is called before all request are processed. How can i correct this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try with *done* instead of *then* on your *when* ?
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Also, you might consider *all* method from *JS promises* :

```
let promises = [];
promises.push(aPromise);
promises.push(anotherPromise);
Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  // All requests are done
}).catch(error => {
  // Handle error
});
```